# jquery closest() cannot work in each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, shiny

Hello I would like to send the following jQuery script as a custom message to ui in Shiny, so as to find the row, in which the first td is found with cell value "(all)", and then change the font color of the row:

```
script <- "$('#pivottbl tr td:first-child').each(function() {
              var cell = $(this).text();
              if (cell == ' (all) ') {
                  $(this).closest('tr').css('color', 'red');
              }
              else {
                  $(this).closest('tr').css('color', 'black');
              }
           })"
```

However, the above doesn't work. I deleted `closest('tr')` to test if I can catch the first td containing the cell value(see code below), it worked!

```
$('#pivottbl tr td:first-child').each(function() {
              var cell = $(this).text();
              if (cell == ' (all) ') {
                  $(this).css('color', 'purple');
              }
              else {
                  $(this).css('color', 'black');
              }
          })
```

So my question is what went wrong with use of `closest('tr')`? I'd like to change the color for the row containing this cell, what should I do?

Comment: Have you tried with `parent()` instead of `closest()`? The `parent()` function get the immediate parent of an HTML tag, in your case should be the `tr` of the `td:first-child`.

Comment: Your code works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/s8dnjktb/

Comment: @YulioAlemanJimenez Won't the immediate parent always be the closest element as well?

Comment: @YulioAlemanJimenez I tried it, it didn't work either. I think closest() works the same as parent() here.

Comment: @Barmar I don't know why it didn't work when I run the script in Shiny. Do you have any idea of using jQuery in Shiny? I used session$sendCustomMessage to send the script from server to ui, where the script is received by addCustomMessageHandler. The set up works with the second script, not the first one.

Comment: I've never even heard of Shiny before, I have no idea how it works or why this wouldn't work with it.